# Database better inner join for performance in this case

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have 2 tables that manages the time spent on doing various things:

```
@times(id, time_in_minutes)
@times_intervals(id, times_id, time_in_minutes, start, end)
```

Then the **@times** might relate to different things:

```
@tasks(id, description)
@products(id, description, serial_number, year)
```

What is the best practice in order to reuse the same **@times** and **@times_intervals** for **@task** and **@products**?

I would think about:

```
@times(+task_id, +product_id) 
// add task_id and product_id to the original @times table
```

But if I do so, when I'd join the **@times** table with **@task** and **@products** table would be slower as should choice between the 2 (**task_id** or **product_id**). When task_id is not null join on the **@tasks** and viceversa.

(I'm using MySQL6)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would drop the time_in_minutes column from the times table.  This information is redundant if it is just the sum of the detail and is a premature optimization.

I would add a product_time table containing product_id, times_id and a task_time table containing task_id, time_id

Then to get the total time with a product:

```
SELECT *
FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_time pt
    ON pt.product_id = p.id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT times_id, SUM(time_in_minutes) as time_in_minutes
    FROM times_intervals
    GROUP BY times_id
) AS t
    ON t.times_id = pt.times_id
```

Typically to make this perform, you would have a non-clustered covering index for times_intervals with columns times_id and time_in_minutes - note that the times table is simply a data-less header table at this point and the only purpose it to group the times_intervals and it's only necessary because you have this very similar arrangement for tasks.

If there were not two (or more) entities using the times_intervals, you might simply put product_id in the times_intervals and treat it as your header/master id.

Comment: What do you think about the other answer example performance related to this example? because a task will have only 1 time, and a product also.

Comment: @Totty I think you need to rephrase your question in terms of the actual problem domain.  It's too difficult to model data if you aren't able to see the true meaning of the data.

Comment: @Totty - What is a "time"?  What is a "task"?  Why is a "time" linked to a "task" or the other way round?  Why is a "product" linked and what is a product?  Because this is a data modeling question.

Comment: @Totty - This is also not a performance issue at this point.  First you need to have an accurate model.  An INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN or no join is a semantic thing determined by your data model and the relationship between the data entities.  Once you have a good idea of the model you can see if it will need to be altered (perhaps denormalized) for efficiency based on volume and usage patterns.  Everything is fast for small N.

Comment: Time contains the total time to do a task/product; TimeIntervals are intervals that summed will determine the total time; And any task/product will have only one total time; (to do a car (product) it takes 4 hours (time));

Comment: @Totty - I rewrote my answer to take account of your business domain

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest against adding an `id` column to `times` for every table you might join it to. It would break normalization and make joins much more complicated.

If you only have one time (or time interval) for a task or a product, make a column in that table that references the `times` table. Otherwise, you could make a separate table like

```
@multitimes(multi_id, time_id)
```

where the two columns together are a primary key, and then have `products` and `tasks` reference `multi_id`. Then each record in each of those tables can be related to any number of times without any conflicts.